# Is there a special name for this dependency of objective functions? $f(x) < f(y) \implies g(x) < g(y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, relations

I am trying to define an objective function for my optimization problem and I came up with several alternatives, while it is not clear, which one is the most relevant.

But I think it would be nice if there was some sort of *consistency* relationship between these functions. For example, if $f,g: X \mapsto 
 \mathbb{R} $ are two objective functions, then for each $x,y \in X$ I would like to have:

$$
f(x) < f(y) \implies g(x) < g(y)
$$

I am surely not the first one to think in such a manner, so I would like to ask if there is some special name for this relationship between functions.

The closest I got was by reading section 2 of [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377221714008662/1-s2.0-S0377221714008662-main.pdf?_tid=52133364-4ac5-11e7-beca-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1496759880_223f07d1fb58ead107274bdaa04a11b4), where they define a so called *relation refinement*. That means, that the relation of total preoder induced by $g$ is a refinement of the one induced by $f$. However, I couldn't find any definition dealing with functions $f,g$ themselves.